# Remove tuple key duplicate with certain value Scala 2.11.12

Tags: scala, set, maps

I have a set of tuples:

```scala
Set(("autumn",0), ("winter",2), ("summer",0), ("winter",0), ("spring",0))
```

How can I remove the tuple which is an key duplicate and has the value 0?

Result:

```scala
Set(("autumn",0), ("winter",2), ("summer",0), ("spring",0))
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What didn't work?

Comment: @GaëlJ If converting the set to an map duplicate keys get removed but I am not sure how to remove the tuple with the zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the first element of the tuples then sort the values and take first element:

```scala
val mySet = Set(("autumn", 0), ("winter", 2), ("summer", 0), ("winter", 0), ("spring", 0))

val result = mySet.groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.toList.sortBy(-_._2).head)
  .values.toSet

//scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, Int)] = Set((winter,2), (autumn,0), (spring,0), (summer,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can group by first element of tuple and select maximum for second one:

```scala
val values = Set(("autumn",0), ("winter",2), ("summer",0), ("winter",0), ("spring",0))
val result = values 
    .groupMap(_._1)(_._2) // groups by first element and maps group values to second
    .map(t => (t._1, t._2.max))
```

Or reusing original values with just `groupBy`:

```
val result = values
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .map(_._2.maxBy(_._2))
```